# Effectiveness of TLB

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, paging

This is a book question:

> Suppose that a machine has 48-bit virtual addresses and 32-bit
>   physical addresses.
>
> Suppose this same system has a TLB (Translation Lookaside Buffer) with
>   32 entries. Furthermore, suppose that a program contains instructions
>   that fit into one page and it sequentially reads long integer elements
>   from an array that spans thousands of pages. How effective will the
>   TLB be for this case?

Answer: I think that we cannot know the effectiveness of the TLB because we do not know the number of instructions the program has. I hope I make sense.

source:
Modern Operating Systems
Question 15, chapter 3
ISBN-13: 978-0-13-359162-0

Comment: What's your question?  We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about?  If you're not sure whether your answer is correct, there must be  some concept you're not 100% certain about.  Try asking a question about that concept.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming size of long is $32$ bits, each page frame in physical memory exactly contain $1$ long number, therefore in $TLB$ at particular instance of time $31$ long integers would be present. Hence, $1$ page fault in every $32$ memory accesses. Now, I am not sure what is criteria of effectiveness here. But $1$ per $32$ memory access seems pretty good.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that a page will only hold one long element (a 64-bit machine, implied by 48-bit VA, might use I32LP64, pages are likely at least 4 KiB), so since the array accesses as sequential (no reuse) every page_size/long_size data accesses will generate a TLB miss. If the TLB uses pseudo-random or FIFO replacement, the entry for instructions will be victimized occasionally.

Comment: This calculation doesn't work at all. Under the unrealistic assumption of 1 array element per page, that would rather mean that *every single access* would miss the TLB. 1/32 just comes out of absolutely nowhere.